# Python : binary created in hexadecimals converted to string : how to put it back to binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Someone I work with had a bstring and saved it to a file (with other stuff).
Later, I open the file with pandas and try to read the bstring, but it has been converted to string:

```
import pandas as pd

# Saving value
bstring = b"\x0F\xC8\x3F\x7C\x00"
to_write = 'bstrings\n'
to_write += str(bstring)
with open('test.csv', "w") as f_csv:
    f_csv.write(to_write)

# Reading value
my_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
bstring2 = my_df['bstrings'][0]
print(bstring)
print(type(bstring))
print(bstring2)
print(type(bstring2))
print(bstring == bstring2)
```

The output is :

```
b'\x0f\xc8?|\x00'
<class 'bytes'>
b'\x0f\xc8?|\x00'
<class 'str'>
False
```

bstring2 is now a string containing the characters *b'\x0f\xc8?|\x00'*
(inclusing the b and the quotation marks), not a binary.

How do I transform back `bstring2` to the binary `bstring` ?

I tried `ctypes.fromhex`, which raises a `ValueError`

I found a few related questions but they did not seem to answer my question.

Comment: Note what you call a "bstring" is a _`bytes` object_, `b"whatever"` is just one way to create/display it. `str(bstring) == repr(bstring)`, if you want the _value_ you should be more specific about how to decode the bytes.

Comment: You need to open the file in `"wb"` mode and simply write the `bytes` data.

Comment: @tripleee: If they're really trying to write out CSV data, you can't write raw binary to a CSV. The question is a little strange, since it writes raw data (a mix of a string and the bytes literal), then tries to read it as CSV. I don't think your duplicate is a good target; it *might* be, but only if the real answer turns out to be "The OP doesn't want CSV in the first place".

Comment: The CSV indeed contains mixed the bytes literal and plaintext, so the linked question does not answer. @ShadowRanger's answer does, I'll accept it when I can.

Comment: Your mistake is calling `str(bstring)`. Calling `str` on a bytes object is hard to reverse. Try to encode it in a simpler format

Comment: @mousetail sometimes you can't change other people's code unfortunately, whic is why I was asking about the decoding part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any string representing a legal Python literal and convert it back to what it represents with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

So in your code, just change:

```
bstring2 = my_df['bstrings'][0]
```

to:

```
bstring2 = ast.literal_eval(my_df['bstrings'][0])
```

adding an `import ast` to the top of your file, and `bstring2` will store the same value as `bstring`.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding a bytes object using `str()` is inefficient, mainly meant to be readable by humans but not efficient to read by computers. Better to use base16 or base64 encoding.

```py
import pandas as pd
import base64

# Saving value
bstring = b"\x0F\xC8\x3F\x7C\x00"
to_write = 'bstrings\n'
to_write += base64.b64encode(bstring).decode('utf-8')
with open('test.csv', "w") as f_csv:
    f_csv.write(to_write)

# Reading value
my_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
bstring2 = base64.b64decode(my_df['bstrings'][0].encode('utf-8'))
print(bstring)
print(type(bstring))
print(bstring2)
print(type(bstring2))
print(bstring == bstring2)
```

Base64 is a very compact way to store bytes in text format. Many others are available though, take a look at the [base64 module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) (Standard Library)